# Which Azure services are PaaS

Tags: azure

I'm trying to compare AWS and Azure for a custom web app that's essentially like any canned content management system. It requires web hosting, database, email, storage, security, some way to process ASP.NET but with high availability and load balanced.

The PaaS/IaaS distinction can sometimes be grey (in part because companies tend to use marketing jargon that portrays IaaS type services as maintenance free). From a small business perspective its quite clear though. If a service involves the SMB spend time maintaining rather than developing, its in the IaaS camp. Since I'm a single developer with limited time, a PaaS model for all services would be preferable. The ideal would be all services (web hosting, database, email, etc are offered as a zero maintenance scalable service rather than have to spin up and manage individual instances.

I find AWS can do everything but a drawback is that one still needs to manage instances (i.e. I would need to keep the software on instances updated, track instances, manage network, security, etc.) S3 doesn't process scripts. AWS Beanstalk and Optworks are still essentially mostly helper apps for starting up an IaaS type environment. (whereas say DynamoDB would count as a PaaS type service). Recently Microsoft has dropped prices on Azure which makes it an attractive alternative

In short, I am looking for a list of services offered by Azure which are actually no maintenance services that don't require I patch software or need to spin up instances to handle traffic spikes (e.g. web hosting, script processing, database, email, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

> web hosting, database, email, storage, security, some way to process ASP.NET but with high availability and load-balanced

All of the above are standard features which any matured cloud provider will have in the toolkit. In regards to MSFT Azure:

1. For web hosting - you have PaaS solutions such as App service plan
   and App service environment. The upkeep of the platform (as the name suggests) is with Azure but note that any components that you deploy as part of the package belong to dev and test teams respectively
2. For database and storage - for a complete PaaS solution you have Azure SQL Server Database and Azure SQL Server Managed Instances, but as I said earlier you will anyways have to own any custom deployment (security policies, VNET injection and IAM's yourself)